# How to sumarize rows in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a question that is more like a way to find a idea to how to solve my problem.

So the problem:

Every 2 minutes I receive a new line at my table with various information. Are they:

```
ID_VEIC - Vehicle ID
DT_POSI - Position date
LAT - latitude
LONGI - longitude
SPEED - car speed when positioning
GMT - Vehicle gmt.
```

Several of these positions come with speed equal to zero, indicating, in my case, that the vehicle is stopped.
If there are several positions of the vehicle stopped (speed = 0) I have to bring in the select only the last position of the stop between two movement positions.

Explaining with images:

[image: Table img]

In the image, two lines are selected where the speed is 0. I need to somehow show only the last line of that period, in the case of line 11 and still bring all the other lines where the speed is > 0.

In more detail here:

Current resultset:

```
ROWNUM  ID_VEIC    DAT_POSI              LAT            LONGI   SPEED        
1   1211678   06/08/2020 06:08  -254.454.135       -544.047.225   15    
2   1211678   06/08/2020 06:38  -25.445.364        -544.047.383   20    
3   1211678   06/08/2020 07:08  -25.445.401        -54.404.762     0    
4   1211678   06/08/2020 07:38  -254.454.135       -544.046.878    0    
5   1211678   06/08/2020 08:08  -254.454.255       -544.046.828   10    
6   1211678   06/08/2020 08:38  -254.453.996       -54.404.707    25    
7   1211678   06/08/2020 09:08  -25.445.428        -544.047.445   45    
8   1211678   06/08/2020 09:38  -254.454.583       -544.048.415    0
```

Desired resultset

```
 ROWNUM ID_VEIC    DAT_POSI              LAT            LONGI   SPEED        
    1   1211678   06/08/2020 06:08  -254.454.135       -544.047.225   15    
    2   1211678   06/08/2020 06:38  -25.445.364        -544.047.383   20    
    3   1211678   06/08/2020 07:38  -254.454.135       -544.046.878    0    
    4   1211678   06/08/2020 08:08  -254.454.255       -544.046.828   10    
    5   1211678   06/08/2020 08:38  -254.453.996       -54.404.707    25    
    6   1211678   06/08/2020 09:08  -25.445.428        -544.047.445   45    
    7   1211678   06/08/2020 09:38  -254.454.583       -544.048.415    0
```

Line 3 has been removed and only the line that was previously line 4 is shown.

Any idea how to do this?

Below the select used:

```
SELECT  ID_VEIC,
        DAT_POSI,
        LAT,
        LONGI, 
        SPEED,
        GMT
  FROM LITERAL_VIEW   
 WHERE  ID_VEIC= 1211678
   AND DAT_POSI BETWEEN SYSDATE - INTERVAL '2' HOUR AND SYSDATE
   AND ROWNUM <= 999
 ORDER BY ID_VEIC, 
          DAT_POSI;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show your raw data and expected results as formatted text (not images). Sounds like a gaps-and-islands problem but not sure. Why are lat/long changing while speed is zero, and does that matter? Also, filtering by `rownum` *before* ordering gives you an indeterminate set of rows back.

Comment: Agreed. Use `rownum` very carefully when you have open `order by` in your query.

Comment: The lat / long is changing, despite the speed being zero, as I receive a positioning of the vehicle every 2 minutes. In that time the car may have moved a little and stopped again, setting zero speed in a different position, in that interval.
Thanks for the rownum information, and also the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions to filter out rows where `speed` is `0` and whose "next" row has a 0 `speed` too:

```
select id_veic, dat_posi, lat, longi, speed, gmt
from (
    select l.*, lead(speed) over(partition by id_veic order by date_posi) lead_speed
    from literal_view l
) t
where not (speed = 0 and lead_speed = 0)
```

You can easily modify the query to filter on a given date range and/or vehicle, by adding a `where` clause to the subquery.

Comment: add default value of more than 0 for `lead_speed` when there is no more next row, like so `lead(speed,1,1)` so that if the last rows are 0 speed the filter will still work for them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's working! Just a small detail, if all positions have zero speed, when I run this query, no position appears to me. There is some way to show the last position? I put the  'lead (speed, 1,1)'  but still nothing comes.

Comment: If all positions have 0 speed, `lead(speed,1,1) over(partition by id_veic order by dat_posi) lead_speed` worked for me and only the last row is displayed.